# error in import form node_module packages in react

Tags: reactjs, react-codemirror

```js
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
```

error occured is

> ERROR in ./src/components/Editor.js 7:0-39
> Module not found: Error: Package path ./lib/codemirror.css is not exported from package C:\Users\mural\OneDrive\Desktop\new react projects\codepen\node_modules\codemirror (see exports field in C:\Users\mural\OneDrive\Desktop\new react projects\codepen\node_modules\codemirror\package.json)

> ERROR in ./src/components/Editor.js 8:0-39
> Module not found: Error: Package path ./theme/material.css is not exported from package C:\Users\mural\OneDrive\Desktop\new react projects\codepen\node_modules\codemirror (see exports field in C:\Users\mural\OneDrive\Desktop\new react projects\codepen\node_modules\codemirror\package.json

i had try to delete and reinstall modules but has no result

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` and do a `fresh install` of these packages using command, `npm install`, `yarn add` or other package managers.